# Efficiently select key value parquet column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm working with a rather sizable parquet table, and 99.9% of the data is contained in a single key:value column. For example:

```py
# Cannot use hive metastore to access so we have to load this way
df = spark.read.parquet('hdfs://cluster/path/to/parquet') \
    .select('id, 'version', 'details')
```

```py
df.printSchema()
>> root
 |-- id: string
 |-- version: string
 |-- details: map
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct
 |    |    |-- complex_struct_1: struct
 |    |    |    |-- complex_substruct_1: struct
 |    |    |    |    |-- ...
 |    |    |    |-- ...
 |    |    |-- complex_struct_2: struct
 |    |    |    |-- complex_substruct_n: struct
 |    |    |    |    |-- ...
 |    |    |    |-- ...
 |    |    |-- complex_field_n: struct
```

The column in question is `details`, possible keys are either `key_1`, `key_2`, both, or none. My question is how can I efficiently select only subfields belonging to `key_1` (e.g. select `details['key_1'].complex_struct_1.complex_substruct_1.field`)?

Because the table is not in the hive metastore, I don't believe I can use spark.sql here, or if there would be any benefit. I understand how to naively load the DB, select the entire details column and then filter, but given that details column is absolutely massive (thousands of fields) and I only want a small subset, I would like to take advantage of the columnar access if possible here. Is this something I could do more efficiently, or is that beyond the capabilities of parquet?

Comment: `df.select(df.details['key_1'].complex_struct_1.complex_substruct_1.field)`?

Comment: @MykolaZotko I was trying something along those lines, but that syntax doesn't appear to work: `TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <bound method alias of Column<b'details[key_1]'>> of type <class 'method'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.`

Comment: Try `df.selectExpr("details['key_1'].complex_struct_1.complex_substruct_1.*")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spark SQL by creating a temp view:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
df2 = spark.sql("""select details['key_1'].complex_struct_1.complex_substruct_1.field from df""")
```

which should be efficient and supposedly only fetches the subset of results that you need. You can do `df2.explain()` to see how the query is actually executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This seems closer to what I'm looking for. I was having a hard time finding good documentation for if key/value lookups on parquet tables load all columns or not. Are you aware of the details on how `details['key_1']` is evaluated? Looking at the execution plan it seems to be only taking the target field.

Comment: @Brendan I believe the execution plan will tell you about how it's evaluated. If you're interested in the deep details you'll have to look through the source code, but most of the time the execution plan should provide all that you need/want.